'In' operator in mySQL
Employee:
+-----+-------+------------+-----------+
| id  | name  | department | managerId |
+-----+-------+------------+-----------+
| 101 | John  | A          | null      |
| 102 | Dan   | A          | 101       |
| 103 | James | A          | 101       |
| 104 | Amy   | A          | 101       |
| 105 | Anne  | A          | 101       |
| 106 | Ron   | B          | 101       |
+-----+-------+------------+-----------|

From the above Employee table, we need the names of managers who manages at least 5 employees.
I came up with this query:
select name from employee where managerid in (
select managerid from employee where managerid is not null group by managerid having count(*) > 4
);

I expected the following output:
+------+
| name |
+------+
| John |
+------+

But instead, it throws up:
| name  |
| ----- |
| Dan   |
| James |
| Amy   |
| Anne  |
| Ron   |

The where clause returns the managerid as 101. But the final select is not picking up the corresponding name. Where is this going wrong?

Because you're querying by manager ID and retrieving the name of the managed employee. I think you want to query by id.

Execute the subquery standalone, and see what i returns.

If you have lots of ids, the EXISTS clause is likely to perform much better than the IN operator.

You are selecting all employees with a manager who has more than 4 employees. You need to change the where clause to filter by id instead of managerid:
select name from employee where id in (
    select managerid 
    from employee 
    where managerid is not null 
    group by managerid having count(*) > 4
);

